# Download created file without filename

Tags: php

Basically i have input box where user give filename and click download. What i want is if user enter  " .txt " without quotes, then i need downloaded file with exact file extension , But in my code it created file with given name of extension like "  txt "  filename. I want filename " .txt  "

```
<?php
$folname = 'createfile';    
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$folname.'/';

if(isset($_POST['filename']) && !empty($_POST['filename'])){        
    fopen($_POST['filename'],'w');          
    downloadfile($filepath.$_POST['filename'],$_POST['filename']);
}else{
    echo '
            <h1>Enter Filename Or Extension, Download the empty file</h1>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename" />
                <input type="submit" name="download" id="download" value="download"/>
            </form>     
    ';
}

function downloadfile($filepath,$filename){ 
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    @readfile($filepath);
    unlink($filepath);      
}?>
```

Comment: Usually the `filename` value inside a `Content-Disposition` header is put in double quotes. And if that doesn’t help – then maybe the browser or OS just doesn’t want to accept that as a filename.

Comment: i have tried this but doesn't work..

Comment: Usually most Operating systems will not accept filenames like .txt .doc, you have to have a name for it.